# The Component Installer in Android studio is taking too long

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I installed android studio yesterday. Today noon, I started updating the SDK tools but, I am afraid, it takes too long to update. It's been over 8 hours and the download has not yet completed. It seems that the download progress has literally stuck there itself.

Also, it's mentioned `gradle build in 15s 136ms(15 minutes ago)`. It's been hours so how can it be still "15 minutes ago"? I am really stuck and confused as to what to do next? Should I wait to get it downloaded or should I abort it? Will this download ever end? Kindly refer to the attached image for a better view of the problem.

[image]